# SELECT default text doesn't show full text on page load in IE9

Tags: html, select, internet-explorer-9

I am a Front-end developer and a colleague of my has a problem in IE9. The default text of a couple of select-fields doesn't show properly (see link for screenshot). The problem is that she is the only one (so far) with this problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXo79.jpg

The code of the SELECT statement + CSS:

```
<div class="formRow">
   <label>
       Ingeschreven:
   <Label>
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="RequiredCourseStatusIsRegisteredDropDownList">
        <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources: CommonStrings, DefaultSelectOptionText %>" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources: CommonStrings, Yes %>" Value="true"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources: CommonStrings, No %>" Value="false"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
```

```
select
{
    float: left;
    width: 203px; /* with (including borders, padding and margin) is a multiple of 75px column with */
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid #e6deca;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px;
    height: 20px;
}
label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 220px;
}
.formRow
{
    background: #f3efe5;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 4px 0;
}
```